# Javascript loads twice, declares different values on the same array, how to keep each value?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    var clientData = [];
    clientData.push("{{ $field['entity'] }}");
    console.log(clientData);
</script>
```

There are 2 fields on the form, therefore the above script loads twice.

However, instead of adding a new array, it overwrites clientData[0].

The above will output this on the console:

```
["employee"]
["type"]
```

When I type clientData[0] on the console, I get:

```
"type"
```

Is it humanly possible to preserve the first declaration?

Comment: Even loading twice this code will not append or change data in current array - it recreate array `clientData = []` and then insert new data. So find problem in your insertion

Comment: Can't you just push these both values at once? Instead of calling the function twice?

Comment: If I call the function once, what happens is that it only adds the value of the first field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assign the variable `clientData` to an empty array each time, you will always end up with the last value added. You will have to declare `clientData` somewhere else in your code (and also before trying to push data to the array), then you won't lose the values you push to the array.

So something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    var clientData = [];
</script>
...
<script>
    clientData.push("{{ $field['entity'] }}");
    console.log(clientData);
</script>
...
<script>
    clientData.push("{{ $field['entity'] }}");
    console.log(clientData);
</script>
```

This should output:

```
["employee"]
["employee", "type"]
```

Comment: I see what you mean, trying to figure out where to load it though.

Comment: Used requirie_once and loaded a php file with the script. Lo and behold, it worked, thanks.